# Deploying Node. js application to Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, selenium-webdriver, npm

I am getting following error when I am deploying Rest service(Build on Node.js environment using npm and selenium web driver) on Azure.

iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.

HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500
HTTP subStatus: 1002
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error
You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/iisnode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The node.exe process has not written any information to stderr or iisnode was unable to capture this information. Frequent reason is that the iisnode module is unable to create a log file to capture stdout and stderr output from node.exe. Please check that the identity of the IIS application pool running the node.js application has read and write access permissions to the directory on the server where the node.js application is located. Alternatively you can disable logging by setting system.webServer/iisnode/@loggingEnabled element of web.config to 'false'.

Can anyone gives a solution to this ????

Comment: I'm actually hitting the exact same wall.  Can you share your web.config and iisnode.yml ?

Comment: I noticed that you have selenium web driver in your app, as doc mentioned [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks), selenium is not supported.

Comment: have you fixed it?

Comment: No. Any solution to this error will be a great help to me

Answer (score 2):

as per this [doc](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks), the selenium web driver is not supported, maybe it's the cause.